# How would I add an object with an int and a string value to an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

So far for the class I have:

```
public class Candidate
 {
// instance variables
private int numVotes;
private String name;

// Constructor for objects of class Candidate
public Candidate(String name, int numVotes)
{
    // initialize instance variables
    this.name = name;
    this.numVotes = numVotes;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public int getVotes()
{
    return numVotes;
}

public void setVotes(int n)
{
    numVotes = n;
}

public void setName(String n)
{
    name = n;
}

public String toString()
{
    return name + " received " + numVotes + " votes.";
}
}
```

I have a tester class where I have an array that I want to add the objects to. The tester class so far is:

```
 public class ElectionTesterV1
 {
Candidate Candidate[] = new Candidate[5];
 }
```

So far I have tried

```
 Candidate[0] =  ("John Smith",5,000);
```

but I get lost of errors illegal start type and identifier needed. How would I add an object with the same format with a name and then a number into the array. I'm supposed to be using an array, not an arraylist

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/deSnxIa getting the same errors and for some odd reason after the Candidate[0, it's saying I need a ] when there is one.

Comment: `Candidate [] cd = new Candidate[5];`. Followed by - `cd[0] = new Candidate("John Smith", 5000);`

Comment: Still getting the errors

Comment: Check 2nd picture of the link

Comment: Jesus christ i'm an idiot, i forgot to say public static void main(String[] args) { at the start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is `Candidate[]`, so therefore it needs to hold instances of `Candidate`. The class `Candidate` may be instantiated with a `String` and and `int` (per the constructor).

Note: I changed the array name to `candidates` (plural) to help distinguish the usage.

You can add to the array by:

```
// create the array
Candidate[] candidates = new Candidate[5];

// add the first person
candidates[0] = new Candidate("John Smith", 5000);
```

So the test class might look like:

```
public class ElectionTesterV1
{
  // array of Candidate objects called candidates
  Candidate[] candidates = new Candidate[5];
  candidates[0] = new Candidate("John Smith", 5000);
  candidates[1] = new Candidate("Mary Sue", 8765);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, just tells me identifier expected after Candidates[], this is so wierd

Comment: @user9986762, the issue is the definition, and it appears I cannot type this evening. But it has to be `Candidate[] candidates = new Candidate[5];` or similar. Your current example has a class and then an array definition.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/deSnxIa, check picture 2, added that but i'm getting the same errors and for some odd reason after the Candidate[0, it's saying I need a ] when there is one

Comment: Jesus christ i'm an idiot, i forgot to say public static void main(String[] args) { at the start